# Android: automatic animation

Tags: android

I have a Button that needs to be slide in from the bottom automatically after the activity starts for 5 seconds. How do I do that? There shouldn't be any user intervention (Should be done without click).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using Tween animation.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween

set field 
android:startOffset="5000" 
in xml with your animation for start delay

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer to start the animation, whenever you want.

Check this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

You will have to implement a Runnable that creates and runs or just runs the animation.